# What does $f(x)=(x\cos(x),\ x\sin(x),\ x )$, $f:[0,5]\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ look like in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out how to draw this function in $\mathbb R^3$, and I just can't know how to think about it in the plane.
Is it a ball with radius $t$ and height $t$?

Is there a good way to *see* these kind of functions easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we write it as follows,

$$\vec r(t)=\langle t\cos t,t \sin t, t \rangle$$

Then we are able to see that $x^2+y^2=t^2$. As $t$ increases from $0$ we get higher an higher up the path, but the points stay circular in nature. The circles that a single point $(t\cos(t),t\sin(t),y\sin (t))$ are at get bigger as $t$ gets bigger or smaller from $0$.

The path looks like a spiral as,

[image]

It is easy to see that $t$ behaves just like the polar angle $\theta$ when $t>0$ because $\vec r(t)=t \langle \cos t,\sin t,1 \rangle$. So if we just plotted , in a way level points for the path with $t>0$, we would get $x^2+y^2=t^2=\theta^2$ that tells us that the level points together look like $r=\theta$ which indeed is well known to be a "spiral".

Answer (score 3):

A function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ generally looks like a path in space. In this case, the path begins at the point $(0,0,0)$ and spirals upward with an increasing radius, basically winding around an up-ward opening cone.

A good way to "see" such a function is to look at projections: Ignore the $z$-component, and [you'll get a bird's-eye-view](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3Dt*cos(t),+y%3Dt*sin(t),+t%3D0+to+5) Ignore the $x$- or $y$-component, and [you'll get a side view](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3Dt*cos(t),+y%3Dt,+t%3D0+to+5).

Comment: See [full plot here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d+parametric+plot+%7Bt*cos(t),+t*sin(t),+t%7D+for+t+%3D+0..5).

Comment: Thanks for the hyperlink edits. I didn't know how to do that right.

Comment: +1 for the comment "a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ generally looks like a path in space."

Answer (score 1):

To imagine such a curve you should think bout what is occurring in each coordinate. As $x$ ranges over $[0,5],$ the first or '$x$' coordinate is a version of cosine, which is growing in amplitude, since $x$ is an increasing function. Similarly, with the '$y$' coordinate, however here we have sine with increasing amplitude. In the '$z$' coordinate you get just $x$, so you're meant to imagine what is happening in $x$ and $y$ being lifted upward as it progresses, rather than only occurring in the $xy-$plane.

To imagine how it looks entirely, you should look at what is occurring in the $x$ and $y$ coordinates. You'll notice that there is a copy of cosine and sine, so the function will have a rotation pattern with a standard counter clockwise orientation, but growing outward due to the increasing amplitude.

So in totality you want to see that you're drawing the graph of $(x\cos x, x\sin x)$ and "pulling it upward" as you draw it.

In general, as the other answer suggests, is to look at the components of the function and understand each of those behaviors. Taking "snapshots," so to speak, and then getting an idea of how the function behaves by stirring in the new parameters.